# POST form data using WinInet c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, forms, wininet

I'm trying to make this program connect to a website and submit form data in order to login, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have heard of others like curl and Winsock but I chose the WinINet library. So just for the testing of this program I've been using the website Pastebin to post to. So far, I haven't seen any results from this. If this program succeeds in posting the form data it will give me the header to the location of the post on their site.

Am I writing the form data char* correctly? I have seen on other stackoverflow posts where they had a large amount of dashes before some number then the put their form data.

Do I need to add something to it make it simulate clicking the submit button?
Do I need to write out values for each elements on the form?

I have tried HttpAddRequestHeaders and that didn't help me.

Also, I get the ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER error on HttpOpenRequest but it still returns a valid HINTERNET.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinInet.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment( lib,"Wininet.lib")
using namespace std;

char* getheaders(HINTERNET hRequest){
    DWORD dwInfoLevel=HTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF;
    DWORD dwInfoBufferLength=10;
    char* pInfoBuffer=(char*)malloc(dwInfoBufferLength+1);
    while(!HttpQueryInfo(hRequest,dwInfoLevel,pInfoBuffer,&dwInfoBufferLength,NULL)){
        if (GetLastError()==ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER){
            free(pInfoBuffer);
            pInfoBuffer=(char*)malloc(dwInfoBufferLength+1);
        }else{
            fprintf(stderr,"HttpQueryInfo failed, error = %d (0x%x)\n",GetLastError(),GetLastError());
            break;
        }
    }
    pInfoBuffer[dwInfoBufferLength] = '\0';
    return pInfoBuffer;
}

void readfile(HINTERNET hRequest,char** buffs,int size){
    DWORD dwBytesAvailable;
    DWORD dwBytesRead;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(!InternetQueryDataAvailable(hRequest,&dwBytesAvailable,0,0)) break;
        buffs[i]=(char*)malloc(dwBytesAvailable+1);
        bool bResult=InternetReadFile(hRequest,buffs[i],dwBytesAvailable,&dwBytesRead);
        if(!bResult | dwBytesRead==0) break;
    }
}


int main(int argc,char** argv){
    char* hdrs="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    char* frmdata="paste_code=test";
    LPCSTR accept[2]={"*/*", NULL};

    HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpen("http generic",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect(hSession, "www.pastebin.com",INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 1);
    HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, "GET","/", NULL, NULL, accept, 0, 0);
    //ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER (122) with "accept".

    bool send=HttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), NULL,NULL);
    if(!send){
        printf("HttpSendRequest failed, code=%d",GetLastError());
        system("pause>nul");
        return 0;
    }

    char* heads=getheaders(hRequest);
    printf("%s\n\n\n\n",heads);

    HINTERNET hRequest2 = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, "POST","/", NULL, NULL, accept, 0, 0);
    //ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER (122) with "accept".

    send=HttpSendRequest(hRequest2, hdrs, strlen(hdrs), frmdata,strlen(frmdata));
    if(!send){
        printf("HttpSendRequest failed, code=%d",GetLastError());
        system("pause>nul");
        return 0;
    }

    heads=getheaders(hRequest);
    printf("%s\n\n\n\n",heads);

    InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);
    InternetCloseHandle(hRequest2);
    InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
    InternetCloseHandle(hSession);

    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you making two requests?  I don't know the specifics of pastebin but you should probably just be making the POST request.  Also, I really doubt you should be posting to the root directory.  The GetLastError() codes are only meaningful if the function fails.  It seems like you are using the Content-Type and form data correctly.

Comment: I've tried just doing a POST but that didn't work. I thought that I might of needed to get the cookies or headers from the website first. Using Chrome to find out how it uses POST and GET, it would GET from the site itself then POST to /post.php and I have tried that as well.

Comment: Here's what goes out over the wire when posting on their web page (http://pastebin.com/qjLbBt9H); it is using the multipart/form-data format.

Comment: Ever since your last post I've been using a packet sniffer (Wireshark) to see the difference of what the browser is doing compared to what I've been doing. So far, the result is still "You cannot create an empty paste.". Im thinking its because the code before the form data changes each time. "------WebKitFormBoundary________________"

Comment: Yeah, I am getting the same thing even with posting seemingly identical data via WinINet.  Maybe they are doing something sneaky on the server side...

Comment: Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63274375/1204153) on how to post JSON data. Maybe you can migrate it to do form url-encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is nearly correct, you must make sure of the following points:

1. `char* hdrs="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";`
          you must make sure that your return object from POST message will be of type `x-www-form-urlencoded` or `JSON` .  if it's JSON you
   need to define  `char* hdrs="Content-Type: application/json\r\n";` 
   Note: you must append `\r\n` to the hdrs.
2. try to call readFile method with buffer of size 10000 for example
   and print buffer , it will print the output of the response to the
   connection
3. In `HINTERNET hRequest2 = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, "POST","/", NULL, NULL, accept, 0, 0);` instead of "/" you must call the path of
   the requested API  for example: .
   In  `HINTERNET hRequest2 = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, "POST", "/users/jsonlogin", NULL, NULL, accept, 0, 0);`