# Sending Discord Webhook using Wininet

Tags: c, discord, wininet

Im trying to send a webhook to the following url:

https://discord.com/api/webhooks/781132765195747359/XDXDH08HsJ0GzkYFKvlDFO6QE3MtzKOqIaKpBruLmqLDJPvlLQEuQQNjr_R8x4y9zCjx

My code:

```c
HINTERNET hIntSession = InternetOpenA((""), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);

if (!hIntSession)
{
    return request_data;
}

HINTERNET hHttpSession = InternetConnectA(hIntSession, ("discord.com"), 80, 0, 0, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, NULL);

if (!hHttpSession)
{
    return request_data;
}

HINTERNET hHttpRequest = HttpOpenRequestA(hHttpSession, ("POST"), url.c_str()
    , 0, 0, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);

if (!hHttpSession)
{
    return request_data;
}

char* szHeaders = ("Content-Type: application/json\r\nUser-Agent: License");
char* szRequest = ("{ \"content\": \"test\" }");

if (!HttpSendRequest(hHttpRequest, NULL, 0, szRequest, strlen(szRequest)))
{
    return request_data;
}

CHAR szBuffer[1024] = { 0 };
DWORD dwRead = 0;

while (InternetReadFile(hHttpRequest, szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer) - 1, &dwRead) && dwRead)
{
    request_data.append(szBuffer, dwRead);
}

InternetCloseHandle(hHttpRequest);
InternetCloseHandle(hHttpSession);
InternetCloseHandle(hIntSession);
```

I am not able to post that request yet, the url returns data.

I'm trying to make so it sends a message to my discord channel. It's not working and I'm not sure why.

Comment: On a side note, this code is leaking resources if an error occurs. You have to close all of your open handles before each of the `return`s, not just at the end. Also, you are not passing `szHeaders` to `HttpSendRequest()`.

Comment: I had a lot of edits on my answer, but it's in an acceptable state now. Hopefully you didn't use one of my earlier edits. If so, just grab the one that's there now. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The comment from Remy above mentions missing headers.. That's been fixed along with a few other minor bugs. You can check this against what you have.

```
LPCTSTR szUserAgent = _T("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.74 Safari/537.36 Edg/79.0.309.43");
LPCTSTR szHost = _T("discordapp.com");
LPCTSTR szUrlPath = _T("/api/webhooks/740632765195747359/m8FGH08HsJ0GzkYFKvlDFO6QE3MtzKOqIaKpZH4LmqLDJPvlLQEuQQNjr_R8x4y9zCjx");
LPCTSTR szAcceptTypes[] = { _T("application/json"), NULL };

LPCTSTR szContentTypeHeader = _T("Content-Type: application/json");
LPCSTR szPostData = "{ \"username\":\"ANDY from StackOverflow\", \"content\": \"Test string again\" }";
const DWORD dwPostDataLength = strlen(szPostData);

HINTERNET hIntSession = InternetOpen(szUserAgent, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
if (hIntSession) {
    HINTERNET hHttpSession = InternetConnect(hIntSession, szHost,
        INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, 0, 0, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, NULL);
    if (hHttpSession) {
        HINTERNET hHttpRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hHttpSession, _T("POST"), szUrlPath,
            NULL, NULL, szAcceptTypes,
            (INTERNET_FLAG_NO_COOKIES | INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD | INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE |
                INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE | INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE), 0);
        if (hHttpRequest) {
            if (HttpSendRequest(hHttpRequest,
                szContentTypeHeader, -1, (LPVOID)szPostData,
                dwPostDataLength)) {

                DWORD dwStatusCode = 0;
                {
                    TCHAR szStatusCode[32] = { 0 };
                    DWORD dwStatusCodeSize = sizeof(szStatusCode) / sizeof(TCHAR);
                    if (HttpQueryInfo(hHttpRequest, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE,
                        szStatusCode, &dwStatusCodeSize, NULL)) {
                        dwStatusCode = _ttoi(szStatusCode);
                    }
                }

                //
                // dwStatusCode: [200,299] means success, any other value
                // means something went wrong
                //

                unsigned char* lpResponse = NULL;
                DWORD dwTotalSize = 0;
                {
                    unsigned char* lpBuffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(2048);
                    DWORD dwRead = 0;
                    while (InternetReadFile(hHttpRequest, lpBuffer, sizeof(lpBuffer), &dwRead) && dwRead) {
                        unsigned char* lpTmp = (unsigned char*)realloc(lpResponse, dwTotalSize + dwRead);
                        if (lpTmp) {
                            lpResponse = lpTmp;
                            memcpy(&lpResponse[dwTotalSize], lpBuffer, dwRead);
                            dwTotalSize += dwRead;
                        }
                        dwRead = 0;
                    }
                    free(lpBuffer);
                }

                //
                // lpResponse now has your data with length of dwTotalSize.
                // Do with it what you want.
                // Keep in mind that a successful request will return
                // no data.
                //

                if (lpResponse) { free(lpResponse); }
            }
            InternetCloseHandle(hHttpRequest);
        }
        InternetCloseHandle(hHttpSession);
    }
    InternetCloseHandle(hIntSession);
}
```

Comment: The url was wrong its actually https://discord.com/api/webhooks/740632765195747359/m8FGH08HsJ0GzkYFKvlDFO6QE3MtzKOqIaKpZH4LmqLDJPvlLQEuQQNjr_R8x4y9zCjx and it isn't posting a message. It does not post the webhook

Comment: @FmalheirFmalheir -- It seems to be working just fine. Updated my answer.

Comment: @FmalheirFmalheir -- According to the documentation, everything is correct: https://dev.to/oskarcodes/send-automated-discord-messages-through-webhooks-using-javascript-1p01

Comment: I still havn't gotten it to work not sure why, https://imgur.com/a/JifV8R8 I saw your messages but mine still dont work, copied your code exactly how it is

Comment: @FmalheirFmalheir -- Holy crap. I figured it out. The host in your URL is wrong. change `www.discord.com` to `discordapp.com`. Updating my answer.

Comment: Go ahead and re-copy/paste code.. I made some final fixes and optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation, it might be useful for someone who has
questions about (there is also an implementation for linux or other OS using dpp)

```cpp
#if defined(WIN32)
void WebHook::closeConnection(HINTERNET hSession /* = nullptr*/, HINTERNET hConnect /* = nullptr*/, HINTERNET hRequest /* = nullptr*/) {
    InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
    InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
    InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);
}
#endif

std::string WebHook::getPayload(std::string title, std::string message, int color) {
    time_t now;
    time(&now);
    struct tm tm;

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    gmtime_s(&tm, &now);
#else
    gmtime_r(&now, &tm);
#endif

    char time_buf[sizeof "00:00"];
    strftime(time_buf, sizeof time_buf, "%R", &tm);

    std::stringstream footer_text;
    footer_text
        << g_configManager().getString(IP) << ":"
        << g_configManager().getNumber(GAME_PORT) << " | "
        << time_buf << " UTC";

    Json::Value footer(Json::objectValue);
    footer["text"] = Json::Value(footer_text.str());

    Json::Value embed(Json::objectValue);
    embed["title"] = Json::Value(title);
    embed["description"] = Json::Value(message);
    embed["footer"] = footer;
    if (color >= 0) {
        embed["color"] = color;
    }

    Json::Value embeds(Json::arrayValue);
    embeds.append(embed);

    Json::Value payload(Json::objectValue);
    payload["embeds"] = embeds;

    Json::StreamWriterBuilder builder;
    builder["commentSyle"] = "None";
    builder["indentation"] = "";

    std::unique_ptr<Json::StreamWriter> writer(builder.newStreamWriter());
    std::stringstream out;
    writer->write(payload, &out);
    return out.str();
}

void WebHook::sendMessage(std::string title, std::string message, int color) {
    std::string webhookUrl = g_configManager().getString(DISCORD_WEBHOOK_URL);
    std::string payload = getPayload(title, message, color);
    // Break empty informations
    if (title.empty() || message.empty() || webhookUrl.empty() || payload.empty()) {
        return;
    }

#if defined(WIN32)
    HINTERNET hSession = InternetOpenA((LPCSTR)STATUS_SERVER_NAME, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if (!hSession) {
        SPDLOG_ERROR("Failed to create WinHTTP session");
        return;
    }

    HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnectA(hSession, "discordapp.com", INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, 0, 0, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, 0);
    if (!hConnect) {
        closeConnection(hSession);
        SPDLOG_ERROR("[WebHook] Failed to connect to Discord");
        return;
    }

    HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequestA(hConnect, "POST", webhookUrl.c_str(), 0, 0, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE, 0);
    if (!hRequest) {
        closeConnection(hSession, hConnect);
        SPDLOG_ERROR("[WebHook] Failed to create HTTP request");
        return;
    }

    std::string contentTypeHeader = "Content-Type: application/json";
    if (!HttpAddRequestHeadersA(hRequest, contentTypeHeader.c_str(), contentTypeHeader.length(), HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_REPLACE)) {
        closeConnection(hSession, hConnect, hRequest);
        SPDLOG_ERROR("[WebHook] Failed to set request headers");
        return;
    }

    // Try to send message
    DWORD dataSize = static_cast<DWORD>(payload.length());
    if (!HttpSendRequestA(hRequest, 0, 0, (LPVOID)payload.c_str(), dataSize)) {
        closeConnection(hSession, hConnect, hRequest);
        SPDLOG_ERROR("[WebHook] Failed to send HTTP request");
        return;
    }

    DWORD statusCode = 0;
    DWORD statusCodeSize = sizeof(statusCode);
    HttpQueryInfoA(hRequest, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE | HTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER, &statusCode, &statusCodeSize, 0);

    if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode >= 300) {
        closeConnection(hSession, hConnect, hRequest);
        SPDLOG_ERROR("[WebHook] Received unsuccessful HTTP status code {}", statusCode);
        return;
    }

    closeConnection(hSession, hConnect, hRequest);
#elif
    dpp::cluster bot("");

    bot.on_log(dpp::utility::cout_logger());

    // Construct a webhook object using the URL you got from Discord
    dpp::webhook wh("https://discord.com/" + webhookUrl);

    // Send a message with this webhook
    bot.execute_webhook_sync(wh, dpp::message(payload));
#endif
}
```

[image]