# Windows: Basic HTTPS Client (not working and questions about that)

Tags: c, windows, sockets, https

I am trying to understand how the Operating System (in my case Windows 10) can create a secure http connection (https) to a server: In my code I am trying to send something to a Discord Webhook(they do not accept http; I already got http working on a different project). Therefor I am trying to solve this using only windows headers.
It took quite a while to find something usable on the internet, and what I found was something from the Windows Documentations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/using-secure-socket-extensions

I am far beyond the point of pretending to understand what is going on there, which is partially because the gcc (my compiler) headers are mostly outdated, which ment, I had to specify some stuff myself. (You can see in the source code bellow. If it is getting replaced with `#defines` in the newer headers, this could cause issues)

I wouldn't write this, if the example code would work: usually `WSASetSocketSecurity` returns 10040, which means that "A buffer passed was too small".
Changing some values in my `SOCKET_SECURITY_SETTINGS` struct prevented this (and no further errors occured), but the webhook sent nothing (I assumed, that for some reason it used a non-secure connection non-the-less).

There are some things I do not understand(, which propably won't solve this issue).

I will not expect all of them to be answered in full detail, as I mainly want to figure out how to make it work now:

- Does `WSASetSocketSecurity` do the same thing/enable the same *security*, as https uses?
- `SOCKET_PEER_TARGET_NAME` has a `PeerAddress`(the IP-Adress). What will be used? The `PeerAddress`, the `AllStrings` (The serverSPN, which seems to be something like an URL) of the same struct, or the `sin_addr.s_addr` member of the `serverAddr` (also the IP) in the `WSAConnect` function call?
- Are there different outputs to be expected, if I use "<" and ">" in the SPN? Is the SPN even in valid format?

Now the code, which doesn't work (of course I removed the webhook of discord and my command line to compile is in the first line)(Please don):

```c
//gcc.exe main.c -o main.exe "C:\Windows\System32\FWPUCLNT.DLL" -lWs2_32

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
//#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum _SOCKET_SECURITY_PROTOCOL {
  SOCKET_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_DEFAULT,
  SOCKET_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_IPSEC,
  SOCKET_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_IPSEC2,
  SOCKET_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_INVALID
} SOCKET_SECURITY_PROTOCOL;

typedef struct _SOCKET_SECURITY_SETTINGS {
  SOCKET_SECURITY_PROTOCOL SecurityProtocol;
  ULONG                    SecurityFlags;
} SOCKET_SECURITY_SETTINGS;

typedef struct _SOCKET_PEER_TARGET_NAME {
  SOCKET_SECURITY_PROTOCOL SecurityProtocol;
  SOCKADDR_STORAGE         PeerAddress;
  ULONG                    PeerTargetNameStringLen;
  wchar_t                  AllStrings[0];
} SOCKET_PEER_TARGET_NAME;

INT WSAAPI WSASetSocketSecurity( SOCKET Socket, const SOCKET_SECURITY_SETTINGS *SecuritySettings, ULONG SecuritySettingsLen, LPWSAOVERLAPPED Overlapped, LPWSAOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE CompletionRoutine);
INT WSAAPI WSASetSocketPeerTargetName( SOCKET Socket, const SOCKET_PEER_TARGET_NAME *PeerTargetName, ULONG PeerTargetNameLen, LPWSAOVERLAPPED Overlapped, LPWSAOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE CompletionRoutine);


//#include <mstcpip.h>
//#include <ws2tcpip.h>
//#include <rpc.h>
//#include <ntdsapi.h>
//#include <tchar.h>


wchar_t URL[] = L"https://ptb.discord.com/api/webhooks/WEBHOOK";


#define PORT 443
//#define REQUEST_SIZE 4096

char message[1024] = "POST /api/webhooks/WEBHOOK HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ptb.discord.com\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n{\"content\": \"Test\"}";
int BufLen = 1024;


//#define RECV_DATA_BUF_SIZE 256

// Link with ws2_32.lib
//#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

// link with fwpuclnt.lib for Winsock secure socket extensions
//#pragma comment(lib, "fwpuclnt.lib")

// link with ntdsapi.lib for DsMakeSpn function
//#pragma comment(lib, "ntdsapi.lib")

// The following function assumes that Winsock 
// has already been initialized

int SecureTcpConnect(const struct sockaddr *serverAddr, ULONG serverAddrLen, const wchar_t * serverSPN)
/**
Routine Description:

    This routine creates a TCP client socket, securely connects to the 
    specified server, sends & receives data from the server, and then closes 
    the socket

Arguments:
    serverAddr - a pointer to the sockaddr structure for the server.
    serverAddrLen - length of serverAddr in bytes
    serverSPN - a NULL-terminated string representing the SPN 
               (service principal name) of the server host computer
    securitySettings - pointer to the socket security settings that should be
                       applied to the connection
    serverAddrLen - length of securitySettings in bytes

Return Value:
    Winsock error code indicating the status of the operation, or NO_ERROR if 
    the operation succeeded.

--*/
{
    int iResult = 0;
    int sockErr = 0;
    SOCKET sock = INVALID_SOCKET;

    WSABUF wsaBuf = { 0 };
    //char *dataBuf = "12345678";
    DWORD bytesSent = 0;

    //char recvBuf[RECV_DATA_BUF_SIZE] = { 0 };
    //DWORD bytesRecvd = 0;
    //DWORD flags = 0;

    SOCKET_PEER_TARGET_NAME *peerTargetName = NULL;
    DWORD serverSpnStringLen = (DWORD) wcslen(serverSPN);
    DWORD peerTargetNameLen = sizeof (SOCKET_PEER_TARGET_NAME) + (serverSpnStringLen * sizeof (wchar_t));

    //-----------------------------------------
    // Create a TCP socket
    sock = WSASocket(serverAddr->sa_family, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, 0, 0);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        iResult = WSAGetLastError();
        printf("WSASocket returned error %ld\n", iResult);
        goto cleanup;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------
    // Turn on security for the socket.

    SOCKET_SECURITY_SETTINGS securitySettings;
    ZeroMemory( &securitySettings, sizeof(securitySettings));
    securitySettings.SecurityFlags = 0x01; //SOCKET_SETTINGS_ALLOW_INSECURE
    securitySettings.SecurityProtocol = SOCKET_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_IPSEC;

    sockErr = WSASetSocketSecurity(sock, &securitySettings, sizeof(securitySettings), NULL, NULL);
    if (sockErr == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        iResult = WSAGetLastError();
        printf("WSASetSocketSecurity returned error %ld\n", iResult);
        goto cleanup;
    }
    printf("behind");
    //-----------------------------------------
    // Specify the server SPN
    peerTargetName = (SOCKET_PEER_TARGET_NAME *) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, peerTargetNameLen);
    if (!peerTargetName) {
        iResult = ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY;
        printf("Out of memory\n");
        goto cleanup;
    }
    // Use the security protocol as specified by the settings
    peerTargetName->SecurityProtocol = securitySettings.SecurityProtocol;
    // Specify the server SPN 
    peerTargetName->PeerTargetNameStringLen = serverSpnStringLen;
    RtlCopyMemory((BYTE *) peerTargetName->AllStrings, (BYTE *) serverSPN, serverSpnStringLen * sizeof (wchar_t));
    //peerTargetName->PeerAddress = inet_addr("162.159.135.232");

    sockErr = WSASetSocketPeerTargetName(sock, peerTargetName, peerTargetNameLen, NULL, NULL);
    if (sockErr == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        iResult = WSAGetLastError();
        printf("WSASetSocketPeerTargetName returned error %ld\n", iResult);
        goto cleanup;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------
    // Connect to the server
    sockErr = WSAConnect(sock, serverAddr, serverAddrLen, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (sockErr == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        iResult = WSAGetLastError();
        printf("WSAConnect returned error %ld\n", iResult);
        goto cleanup;
    }
    // At this point a secure connection must have been established.
    printf("Secure connection established to the server\n");

    //-----------------------------------------
    // Send some data securely
    wsaBuf.len = (ULONG) strlen(message);
    wsaBuf.buf = message;
    //wsaBuf.len = BufLen;

    sockErr = WSASend(sock, &wsaBuf, 1, &bytesSent, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (sockErr == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        iResult = WSAGetLastError();
        printf("WSASend returned error %ld\n", iResult);
        goto cleanup;
    }
    printf("Sent %d bytes of data to the server\n", bytesSent);

  cleanup:
    if (sock != INVALID_SOCKET) {
        //This will trigger the cleanup of all IPsec filters and policies that
        //were added for this socket. The cleanup will happen only after all
        //outstanding data has been sent out on the wire.
        closesocket(sock);
    }
    if (peerTargetName) {
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, peerTargetName);
    }
    return iResult;
}



int main(){
    int iResult;
    SOCKET sock;
    struct sockaddr_in RecvAddr;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData) == SOCKET_ERROR;
    if(iResult != NO_ERROR){
        printf("e");
        return 1;
    }

    RecvAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    RecvAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("162.159.135.232");
    RecvAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    wchar_t daURL[] = L"https://discord.com/";

    SecureTcpConnect((struct sockaddr *)&RecvAddr, sizeof(RecvAddr), daURL);//, &securitySettings, sizeof(securitySettings));

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

(I also switch `daURL` with `URL` in the function call, but it didn't seem to make a difference)

I can only hope that you are't afraid of that long code in here and thank you in Advance for your efforts!

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-wsasetsocketsecurity) seems to say if you want to use `SOCKET_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_IPSEC` you must pass a [SOCKET_SECURITY_SETTINGS_IPSEC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mstcpip/ns-mstcpip-socket_security_settings_ipsec) structure which would have a different size.

Comment: If you need HTTP/S, is there a reason why you are trying to implement it manually with raw Winsock? HTTPS requires TLS security, and AFAIK `WSASetSocketSecurity()` does not support TLS, only IPSEC. To do TLS security with raw Winsock, you need to use SChannel/SSPI (see [Creating a Secure Connection Using Schannel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/creating-a-secure-connection-using-schannel)), or a 3rd party TLS library, such as OpenSSL. Otherwise, use the WinInet/WinHTTP API instead.

Comment: Using the `SOCKET_SECURITY_SETTINGS_IPSEC` doesn't seem to be an option: Why would it need information like a domain or password.
I do realise, that I am making my life more difficult with the choice of using raw sockets. Since my approach from above didn't work, I am going to try it with WinHTTP and maybe later with SChannel, to see how that works. Your comment was exactly what I needed, Remy, thx!

Comment: I Am now succesfully sending stuff to the webhook using wininet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63271595/sending-discord-webhook-using-wininet
(I modified the code slightly to check for some errors n stuff, but it's core is still the same; can only recommend not to use raw sockets, but I still wonder what the answers to the listed questions are)

Comment: @TheA to answer your first question: "*Does WSASetSocketSecurity do the same thing/enable the same security, as https uses?*", the answer is: NO, it does not. You *can't* use `WSASetSocketSecurity()` for HTTPS work, as HTTPS uses TLS over TCP which is not a protocol that `WSASetSocketSecurity()` supports. So you went down the wrong route to begin with.