# How is a valid HTTPS Request Header for Winsock/sockets composed?

Tags: sockets, winapi, websocket, https, request-headers

**Update: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client uses a simple HTTP/1.1 request header to do HTTPS.**

I think I'm having a problem with HTTPS (SSL) in WinSock using its Secure Socket Extensions to establish an HTTPS connection. Note, I have to use SOCKET_SETTINGS_ALLOW_INSECURE (not SOCKET_SETTINGS_GUARANTEE_ENCRYPTION) to make this work, otherwise the connection times out.

Problem is next, I have to send a request header to get the resource, and my website is sending back an error response. For https the Raw header in Firefox looks like the following:

```
            GET / HTTP/2
            Host: www.example.net
            User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/111.0
            Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
            Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
            Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
            DNT: 1
            Connection: keep-alive
            Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
            Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
            Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
            Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
            Pragma: no-cache
            Cache-Control: no-cache
            TE: trailers
```

I get an error message for sending something like this, with just Accept-Encoding and Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1.

```
HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 05 Apr 2023 23:57:10 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 180
Connection: close
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

I've tried things like HTTPS/1.0 as well. I think the site is behind a proxy, and it's forwarding the back-end's response. But anyway, it isn't working.

Comment: HTTP/2 is quite different than HTTP/1.x (there is no HTTPS/1.0). The error is pretty clear that you are sending something that the server doesn't support, so what do *your* request headers actually look like? What does your code look like? Please provide a [mcve]. I've worked with WinSock for 20+ years, but have never used its Secure Extensions, and I've never heard of anyone else using them *successfully* for HTTPS. Most people will just use basic WinSock APIs for plain TCP and then use a separate SSL/TLS library like OpenSSL or SChannel on top of an existing socket to handle the security.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I saw your comment here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69791004/windows-basic-https-client-not-working-and-questions-about-that#comment123364770_69791004) now that suggests this is the wrong API for https, but I think a request-header is still needed, but I'm not sure. (WinInet works with HTTPS without any changes but I've preferred winsock because its connection is stable whereas WinInet's isn't so.) Anyway, seems I chose the wrong API to do this with. But GetAddrInfoW(host,L"https",&hint,&list) suggests it might work with a valid request header. I see you called it HTTP/S?

Comment: @RemyLebeau RE "minimal example" mine looks like the demo code on MSDN except I need SOCKET_SETTINGS_ALLOW_INSECURE to make it work, which may be because I don't have a proper certificate on my website or something. HTTP works. Headers wise I don't know the correct header, but the HTTP header doesn't work is all I know.

Comment: "*I've preferred winsock because its connection is stable whereas WinInet's isn't*" -plenty of apps use WinInet and are stable. And, WinInet uses Winsock internally. So, if you are having stability issues, it's likely an issue in your own code. "*the HTTP header doesn't work*" - again, please show *your* actual code, not someone else's code (which you didn't even indicate which one).

Comment: *"For https the Raw header in Firefox looks like the following: ...."* - This is not the raw header actually send. This is only a string representation for readability of the actual binary header. HTTP/2 does not use a text header like HTTP/1.

Comment: @RemyLebeau RE "WinInet stability" maybe I was using it with satellite Internet, which can be weird, but my code is same as MSDN demo code. Winsock does the same application fast/steady over satellite though. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/using-sspi-with-a-windows-sockets-client looks like what I should be using instead of this (but FWIW I think I saw a reference to Secure Sockets Extensions in one of your comments in another question.) Thanks as always, you're answers/comments have helped me a lot through the past years.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking at isn't the raw header - it is the raw HTTP/2 header *reformatted to make it look like HTTP/1.1*. HTTP/2 is a rather more complex protocol which is also not human-readable, which is why the browser translates the headers to HTTP/1.1 format.

If you just change the `HTTP/2` to `HTTP/1.1` then it is a valid HTTP request.

If you are working with raw HTTP over sockets, then to make things easier for yourself you might want to remove `TE: trailers` and remove `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br` as this will disable some protocol features which could make it easier for you to process the response. Or you could use an actual HTTP library, which will handle all features for you and also implement HTTP/2.